# Matlab install - Java permission denied

Tags: permissions, software-installation, java, matlab

Matlab version 2012. I know there are many threads about this, suggesting to *chmod +x* the following files (if you are in installation directory):

```
sys/java/jre/glnx86/jre/bin/java
sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin/java
```

I also chmodded the *install* file in root of installation directory. However, after running *sudo ./install* I still get:

```
Preparing installation files ...
Installing ...
./install: 1: eval: /tmp/mathworks_4880/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin/java: Permission denied
Finished
```

How is this possible? :)

Comment: If you have extracted the iso then you get this error. Try to mount it. Everything works well after that. (For R2013a Release)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer, no matter how weird it is. The problem was 64bit OS. When I tried with 32bit, Matlab installation worked and every other app I had previously trouble installing. So now I stick to 32bit.

Answer (score 17):

Even at your 64bit system, the installation might as well work out coz i have just successfully installed Matlab2012a in mine... here's what i did.. :

1.in the /matlab-install-files/sys/java/jre/glnx86/jre/bin/java ,i did

```
 sudo chmod +x ./java
```

2.within the installation directory:

```
 sudo chmod +x ./install
```

3.finally, install by:

```
 ./install
```

or

```
 sudo ./install
```

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem with Matlab 2014a, i tried to change permissions of the

```
    sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin/java
```

but it wouldn't i still don't know the reason why, so i took the whole sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre directory and copied it to my Desktop where i changed the permissions to

```
    chmod 777 /home/$USER/Desktop/jre/bin/java
```

and i started the installation with

```
    sudo bash ./install -javadir '/home/$USER/Desktop/jre'
```

and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Installing Matlab (which is 32-bit) on 64-bit Ubuntu causes this problem.
You can try this command and proceed like normal again.

```
ln -s YOURMATLABFOLDER/sys/java/jre/glnx86 YOURMATLABFOLDER/sys/java/jre/glnxa64
```

Comment: This didn't seem to help. See [output](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=aEH94eV8).

Comment: Then I can't help you I'm afraid. This was the suggestion I got from Mathworks support. Didn't really work for me either. Luckily for me I have to run dual boot on this computer, due to other heavy applications that run under windows only.

Answer (score 1):

I did the following on my 64-bit Ubuntu and it worked.

```
chmod +x <MATLAB_DIRECTORY>/sys/java/jre/glnx86/jre/bin/java
```

`<MATLAB_DIRECTORY>` is the directory where you have all the MATLAB installation files in.

Then, in the install script (`<MATLAB_DIRECTORY>/install`), change line 441 from

```
JRE_LOC=
```

to

```
JRE_LOC="<MATLAB_DIRECTORY>/sys/java/jre/glnx86/jre/"
```

And then run ./install in the `<MATLAB_DIRECTORY>`

Answer (score 1):

I tried every solution in here and couldn't install 32-Bit Matlab on 64-bit Linux.

Then I tried this:

> In order to install 32-bit MATLAB on a 64-bit Linux machine, it is
>   necessary to use the -glnx86 flag:
>
> **./install -glnx86**
>
> The -glnx86 flag is required for starting MATLAB. If you are running a
>   license manager, it is required for all license manager scripts as
>   well (lmstart, lmdown, lmstat, etc...).
>
> Some users have problems loading the JRE when running in this
>   configuration. Creating a symlink in $MATLAB/sys/java/jre named
>   'glnxa64' pointing to 'glnx86' should resolve this issue. You can do
>   this with the following command:
>
> **ln -s $MATLAB/sys/java/jre/glnx86 $MATLAB/sys/java/jre/glnxa64**
>
> (where $MATLAB is the MATLAB installation folder) `

Answer (score 0):

You may try this for the 64 bit version if doing chmod on java file doesn't work:

```
-Make a tmp directory in your home directory
-now run install using "./install -tmpdir <path to the above made tmp directory>"
```

Answer (score 0):

In many cases, the file system on which the install disk is mounted, is such that the file's permission cannot be changed to +x. In such cases, open the `install` script, go to somewhere around line which does `echo Installing....` and `eval $java_cmd`. Just put a `read` between these two lines. Then, in another tab, go to `/tmp/mathworks_<some-4-digit-random-number>/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin/` and do `chmod +x java`. Then in the previous tab, press enter.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed the appropriate symbolic link is, instead, something like

ln -s MATLABLOCATION/sys/java/jre/glnxa64 MATLABLOCATION/sys/java/jre/glnx86

If you want to link the missing x86 JRE folder with the existant x64 of your install location.

Answer (score 0):

There's also a file called install_unix which you have to apply the chmod +x trick to. Can't remember which folder it's in, but it'll be clear straight away as it's not in a subfolder.

Also, when you're selecting which components to install, there's a reason the licence manager is automatically not selected. Please leave it unselected - it'll just cause trouble.

Make sure the installation folder is correct, as this can't really be changed otherwise. I had to move it for administrative reasons, but eventually gave up trying and just reinstalled (though that might have cost my University some money).

Another thing that might help is to take the option to install scripts (something like that) so that there's a file you run to actually start MATLAB. You can make do without this option, but then every time you start you'll have to directly access a critical program file, which might be a little bit dangerous. Don't worry about the folder where these scripts are installed, as you can make copies and wherever they are, when run they'll link to the MATLAB root folder.

Once you've installed, it might help to change the startup directory by right clicking in the directory bar and selecting preferences. The startup directory should be where you want to keep MATLAB-related files *you made yourself*, like scripts and functions & maybe results from running them/other data. It might be really dangerous to use the MATLAB root folder for this sort of thing.

It's not necessary to alter the install_info file as the installation options are determined using a dialog box interface.

You might like to install a desktop shortcut to access MATLAB without opening a terminal. For this, the terminal needs to be operated in bash mode. I got the shortcut installed, but I don't think I understand how so I'll leave you to work that out/look it up.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the ISO files instead of Mount and then make the following files executable after ensuring they've got the read-write permission:

1. `install`
2. `/home/amb/I/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin` (all files inside it)
3. `bin/glnxa64/install_unix`

then execute `./install`

Comment: http://installfights.blogspot.in/2017/09/how-to-install-matlab-from-iso-files-in.html - my reference.

Comment: The location of the JRE is probably not under `/home/amb` for other people.