# MATLAB R2014a on Ubuntu 14.04 Install Issue

Tags: command-line, software-installation, matlab

I am trying to install MATLAB R2014a on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I download the .iso file (from my University) and mount it using Disk Image Mounter.  Then I open a terminal, switch to the directory where the image is mounted, and enter this command:

**sudo ./install**

Then it runs a bunch of lines that all say cp: failed to extend '*some stuff*' or cp: error reading '*somestuff*' and then Input/output error.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: are you sure the matlab version is correct?
it might be the win version you are trying to install.

Comment: You can use GNU octave.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I just installed Matlab 2014a from .iso file on Ubuntu 14.04, both 64 bits.

I see there are still issues regarding mounting and installation procedures. My simple experience was just downloading the iso file and extract it there (**not mount**).

Then `chmod +x ./install` replied `permission denied`. This needed making the java file in `/matlab-extracted-folder/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin/` executable using `chmod +x ./java`.

Now come back to the matlab extracted folder and install as `sudo ./install`.

Answer (score 0):

Answer by Sudheer is not correct. Matlab 2014a is available for several Linux distributions, including some Ubuntu versions, however Mathworks does not give any promises about Ubuntu 14.04, but I doubt your problem is the Ubuntu version, unless you are trying to install 64bit Matlab on 32bit Ubuntu. See the link:

http://www.mathworks.se/support/sysreq/current_release/index.html?sec=linux

I suggest you start troubleshooting from: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB

I know it is about Matlab 2012a, not 2014a, but these instructions worked fine with my Ubuntu 12.04 and Matlab 2013b.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case for a new user who is coming here read this answer that's what worked for me:
[Matlab install - Java permission denied](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184703/matlab-install-java-permission-denied)